# API connection for blob storage using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, devops, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I am trying to create API connection using `bicep`. I want to create API connection that connects to Blob Storage using `Managed Identity`. I will use that connection in my `Logic app`.

By hand, i am able to create API connection that uses managed identity:

[image]

But its really hard to reproduce that in `bicep` since its really poor documented.

I prepared code:

```json
resource blobStorageConnection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: 'blobStorageConnection'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    displayName: 'blobStorageConnection'
    api: {
      name: 'azureblob'
      id: '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${resourceGroup().location}/managedApis/azureblob'
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    parameterValues: {
      accountName: 'playtestinga673'
      authenticationType: 'ManagedServiceIdentity'
    }
  }
}
```

But that code throws an error

> {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
> details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "BadRequest",\r\n    "message": "{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'authenticationType' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered..\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":[{\"Message\":\"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'authenticationType' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered..\"},{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\"},{\"ErrorEntity\":{\"ExtendedCode\":\"14022\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:{0}.\",\"Parameters\":[\"errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'authenticationType' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered.\"],\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'authenticationType' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered..\"}}],\"Innererror\":null}"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}

I used command:

```
az rest --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/azureblob?api-version=2016-06-01
```

But that json says nothing to me

My question is, how to create API Connection to blob storage with `Managed identity` using bicep?

Comment: Have you checked this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption#where-you-can-use-a-managed-identity). @michasaucer

Comment: is it for logic app consumption or standard ?

Comment: Can you try to delete the connection and see if the deployment works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> API connection for blob storage using Managed Identity: -

*Use below bicep code to authenticate blob with the managed identity.*

```bash
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param roleDefinitionId string = 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe' //Storage Blob Data Contributor role
var storageAccountName = 'mystoragejama'
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
  }
}

resource blobConnection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: 'xxxxx' //user defined
  location: location
  kind: 'V1'
  properties: {
    alternativeParameterValues: {}
    api: {
      id: 'subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/azureblob'
    }
    customParameterValues: {}
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {}
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Portal view:***

[image]

[image]

Refer [blog](https://medium.com/medialesson/deploying-azure-logic-apps-managed-identity-with-bicep-e1354f185e4d) by @Thomas Pentenrieder for the relevant bicep code structure including logic app too.